# Mysql, date column has empty values after loading from a csv file

Tags: mysql, sql, date, sqldatatypes

I am loading a csv file,

I wanted to create a column with the month and year extracted from a date column. as Jan-2015

my csv file has date stored as dd/mm/yyyy ,

while loading the csv, i put the data type as date and now the column has empty values '0000-00-00'

any reason why that could be?

or could i change the date format while creating a table

```
create table tblname
(Date DATE
id int
region varchar(45));
```

Comment: MySQL expects dates to be in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`. If your dates are in a different format, you need to use `STR_TO_DATE()` to parse them.

Answer (score 0):

Use preprocessing.

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE `filename`
INTO TABLE tablename
{ options }
(@date, id, region)
SET `Date` = STR_TO_DATE(@date, '%d/%m/%Y');
```

[image]

Comment: you don't need to escape forward slashes.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, I guess... but the habit is stronger.

Comment: and i still keep the data type as date?

Comment: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "V://Chai//sales_data_dump.csv" INTO TABLE `sales` 
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
 IGNORE 1 LINES
 SET `Date` = STR_TO_DATE(@date, '%d/%m/%Y');
this is my code, still shows 0000-00-00

Comment: @Chai Add a column `date_txt TEXT` to your table temporarily. Add `date_txt = @date` into SET clause. Then look for raw value - does it is imported correctly, and try to apply STR_TO_DATE to imported raw value - does it is converted correctly?

Comment: could you please explain what and how its happening

Comment: would this work with an update statement?

Comment: @Chai *could you please explain what and how its happening* [LOAD DATA Statement # Input Preprocessing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html#load-data-input-preprocessing). *would this work with an update statement?* "This" - what do you mean?

Comment: it is in the format dd/mm/yyyy in the csv file

Comment: @Chai The screenshot demonstrates that in the file the date is stored in dd/mm/yyyy format. And it is successfully loaded after function usage.